# Sharing state between all instances of same component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Tooltip component that when hovered displays a simple tooltip.

When you `mouseLeave` the component, a `setTimeout` fires, and when it ends, the tooltip is closed (`setState({ open: false })`).

Now I'd like to add a behavior to reflect the one of the native OS tooltips:

When you `mouseLeave` a tooltip, but instantly `mouseEnter` a different tooltip, the previous tooltip is instantly closed, and the new one gets opened.

To do so, I need to have a shared state between all the instances of Tooltip component. I could use Redux but it seems a bit overkill for a so simple task (I'd need a container that interacts with the store and makes an action and a property available).

Are there simpler solutions?

Comment: The most maintainable way to do this is with a flux approach. Redux is not the only option, but I don't think it's overkill for this. If you need global state, use a tool that's built to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share information between ReactComponent is the Flux architecture. [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) is one of them.

A more simple option is to use the [browser native storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) used to store temporary information : it is similar to global variable but with particular scope and duration definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Move the shared state into the `state` of the parent component of all `Tooltip`s, have this parent define a method `setWhatever` to set the value, and pass this method to `Tooltip` components via a property. This way, children can call their `setWhatever` property, which is really the one of their parent, when they need to change the state.

Comment: It's not a solution, this component will be used all around the app. Your method would make the code hard to maintain.